# Azure Key Vault set secret PUT API deprecated?

Tags: rest, azure-keyvault

I'm using the set secret PUT API https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/ to either create or update an existing secret in my key vault.

The API calls still work for me for now. I'm wondering if there will be future changes to this API as the documentation for it is no longer available online and there's only mentions of powershell commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if you are looking for [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/)  , where you can find in keyvault blade > secrets .

[Set-secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/secrets/set-secret/set-secret)
:

```
 PUT {vaultBaseUrl}/secrets/{secret-name}?api-version=7.2
```

> This operation adds a secret to the Azure Key Vault. If it already
> exists, Azure Key Vault creates a new version of that secret. *Needs
> secrets/set permission.*

[Update-secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/secrets/update-secret/update-secret)  :

```
PATCH {vaultBaseUrl}/secrets/{secret-name}/{secret-version}?api-version=7.2
```

> The UPDATE operation changes specified attributes of an existing
> stored secret. This operation requires the secrets/set permission.